# Akka and Android java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class akka.actor

Tags: java, android, akka

Trying to use Akka with android while executing the following line to create an ActorSystem, an exception is thrown

```
final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("OrderManagement");
```

Geting the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class akka.actor.-$$Lambda$yUalsA_HmePIyyKfKknCvUTHge4: scala.Option akka.actor.-$$Lambda$yUalsA_HmePIyyKfKknCvUTHge4.apply() failed to verify: scala.Option akka.actor.-$$Lambda$yUalsA_HmePIyyKfKknCvUTHge4.apply(): [0x4] returning 'Reference: java.lang.Object', but expected from declaration 'Reference: scala.Option' (declaration of 'akka.actor.-$$Lambda$yUalsA_HmePIyyKfKknCvUTHge4' appears in /data/app/com.goldenhorn.vi-HeeWMjjueyCMy6_-AdqGKQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:151)
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion **28**
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage.whatever"
        minSdkVersion **26**
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'

    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-beta03"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"

    implementation 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.20'
    implementation  'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4"
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

build.properties

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true
```

gardle version:

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

Wondering, if anyone else faced such an issue

JK

Comment: We're having the sale issue. Any update on that?